# Defining API route using API versioning in ASP.NET Core 7 Web API

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, asp.net-web-api-routing, .net-7.0

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project and I am facing an issue with defining the API route using API versioning.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Web APIs", Version = "v1" });
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Web APIs", Version = "v2" });
        });
    
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            // Set the default version to 1.0
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            // Add support for versioning via URL segment
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });
```

When I define the route in my controller like this:

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v2/Subscription")]
[Tags("Subscription")]
public class SubscriptionV2Controller : ControllerBase
```

I am getting the following error when trying to access the endpoint:

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
        "Message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:7055/api/v2/Subscription' is not supported.",
        "InnerError": null
    }
}
```

However, if I modify the route as follows:

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Subscription")]
[Tags("Subscription")]
public class SubscriptionV2Controller : ControllerBase
```

The endpoint works fine. The only issue is that the Swagger UI screen doesn't display the expected route.

[image]

I would like to have the route displayed correctly in the Swagger UI while still being able to use API versioning.

[image]

Comment: you did not add version2 `c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Web APIs", Version = "v2" });`

Comment: @jeb I added this, but still same issue. Api responding with error code `UnsupportedApiVersion`

Comment: Hmm,I am not sure. I have a working app with 2 versions but there are many parts not shown in your sample. So i can't pin the exact problem. Maybe this link can help you. https://referbruv.com/blog/integrating-aspnet-core-api-versions-with-swagger-ui/ or someone else can answer it.

Comment: Thanks! @jeb, The URL which you have shared it helps me to resolve my issue.